# Toggle parent DIV's with child elements of similar ID to calculate their price

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

I am trying that, when below page is loaded by default to show **a1** div and just calculate price for that div and display in total e.g. 216.

And when user click on change link/button, it should hide the a1 and display a2 div and calculate the price just for a2 e.g. 201.

Could anyone guide me as to how can this be achieved? have been trying, so far with no luck.

This is the snapshot of the code I am working, representing its logic. I hope it gives clearer picture of my situation.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function prc_calc() {
        $price = parseInt($('#price').attr('value'));
        $quantity = parseInt($('#quantity').attr('value'));
        $sum = $price * $quantity;
        $('#total').text($sum);
    }

    function change() {
        prc_calc();
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        prc_calc();
    }
</script>

<body>
    <div id="a1" style="display:block">
        <span id="price">54</span>
        <span id="quantity">4</span>
    </div>

    <div id="a2" style="display:none">
        <span id="price">67</span>
        <span id="quantity">3</span>
    </div>

    <span id="total"></span>

    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="change();">Change</a>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks all for helping, answers by all works as required, however answers by @ Robert and @ Daniel works with additional functionality of reverting back to div a1 from a2. -> http://jsfiddle.net/5tDUM/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to restructure a few things, firstly having two elements with the same ID is not going to help you. I have restructured using a class called .selected :

http://jsfiddle.net/5tDUM/

CSS:

```
.selected {
    display:block !important;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="a1" style="display:none" class="selected">
        <span class="price">54</span>
        <span class="quantity">4</span>
    </div>

    <div id="a2" style="display:none">
        <span class="price">67</span>
        <span class="quantity">3</span>
    </div>

    <span id="total"></span>

    <a id="changeclick">Change</a>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
function prc_calc() {

        var price = $('.selected .price').text();

        var quantity = $('.selected .quantity').text();
        var sum = price * quantity;
        $('#total').text(sum);

    }

function changeprice() {

    }

    $(document).ready(function() {

        prc_calc();
    });


$('#changeclick').click(function() {
     $('#a1').toggleClass('selected');
     $('#a2').toggleClass('selected');
        prc_calc();


});
```

Comment: thanks @Robert it worked as required, have improved your readability of your code -> http://jsfiddle.net/5tDUM/5/

Answer (score 0):

`ID`'s are meant to be unique. You'd be better of to use `class`.
Alternatively you could get all `span` tags with `flds=document.getElementsByTagName('span')` and reference them like an array: `flds[0]` and `flds[1]` (since every div has 2 spans, price and quantity in that order).

Also, a div is usually a block (by default), so you probably don't need to specify that using inline style declarations.

The anchor is 'weird' to.. try something more sane: `<a href="#" onclick="change(); return false;">Change</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function prc_calc(el) {
    $price = parseInt($('[id="price"]', el).text());
    $quantity = parseInt($('[id="quantity"]', el).text());
    $sum = $price * $quantity;
    $('#total').text($sum);
}

function change() {
    $('#a1').hide();
    prc_calc($('#a2').show());
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    prc_calc($('#a1'));
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3ryKk/)

Note: The ID attribute should be unique in a document, in your case you have the id `price` and `quantity` repeating, you can change it to class attribute.

```
<div id="a1" style="display:block">
    <span class="price">54</span>
    <span class="quantity">4</span>
</div>

<div id="a2" style="display:none">
    <span class="price">67</span>
    <span class="quantity">3</span>
</div>

<span id="total"></span>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="change();">Change</a>
```

Then

```
function prc_calc(el) {
    $price = parseInt($('.price', el).text());
    $quantity = parseInt($('.quantity', el).text());
    $sum = $price * $quantity;
    $('#total').text($sum);
}

function change() {
    $('#a1').hide();
    prc_calc($('#a2').show());
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    prc_calc($('#a1'));
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3ryKk/1/)

Answer (score 0):

first of all.... all your IDs should be unique... (though it may work)... change it to class and you can use hide() and show() to hide and display... `text()` to get the text between the `span` tag.

note: it is always better to use the click event than the inline javascript..

**HTML**

```
<div id="a1" style="display:block">
    <span class="price">54</span>
    <span class="quantity">4</span>
</div>

<div id="a2" style="display:none">
    <span class="price">67</span>
    <span class="quantity">3</span>
</div>

<span id="total"></span>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="change">Change</a>
```

**javascript/jquery**

```
function change(obj1, obj2) {
  $('#' + obj1).show();
  $('#' + obj2).hide();
  $price = parseInt($('#' + obj1).find('.price').text());
  $quantity = parseInt($('#' + obj1).find('.quantity').text());
  $sum = $price * $quantity;
  $('#total').text($sum);
}


$(document).ready(function () {
  change('a1', 'a2');
  $('#change').click(function () {
    change('a2', 'a1')
  });
});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/A2MBp/)

Answer (score 0):

There were a few problems with your code:

- `price` and `quantity` should be classes since there are more than one. `id` needs to be unique.
- You were missing `);` from the end of your document ready.
- You should be specifying the number base in `parseInt()` otherwise weirdness can occur. We want base 10 since we want a decimal number like `parseInt(num, 10)`
- You can add a class `.hide` and toggle it to switch between showing `div`s.
- `val()` is used on `<input>` tags, use `.text()` on `<span>`s to get their text.

Here it is with everything fixed up and working:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/QuWMp/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="a1"> 
    <span class="price">54</span>
    <span class="quantity">4</span>
</div>
<div id="a2" class="hide">
    <span class="price">67</span>
    <span class="quantity">3</span>
</div>
<span id="total"></span>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="change();">Change</a>
```

**JS**

```
function prc_calc() {
    var id = $('#a1').hasClass('hide') ? '#a2' : '#a1';
    var $price = parseInt($(id + ' .price').text(), 10);
    var $quantity = parseInt($(id + ' .quantity').text(), 10);
    var $sum = $price * $quantity;
    $('#total').text($sum);
}

function change() {
    $('#a1,#a2').toggleClass('hide');
    prc_calc();
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    prc_calc();
});
```

Comment: hi Daniel even your code works as required and to precise. However have accepted the answer of @Robert_Owen as he answered first. Thanks you helped me learning something new about hasClass .